# Complex Hessian Signature

Tags: linear-algebra, cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

It' all, simply, about the signature of a matrix.

Let $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb C^n$ open, $r:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ twice differentiable (*real* differentiable, not necessarely complex differentiable, i.e. not necessarely holomorphic), $z_0\in\Omega$.

The Hessian matrix of $r$ in $z_0$ is the $2n\times2n$ matrix 
$$
H[r]_{z_0}=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\partial_{z_i}\partial_{z_j}r(z_0) & \partial_{z_i}\partial_{\bar z_j}r(z_0) \\
\partial_{\bar z_i}\partial_{z_j}r(z_0) & \partial_{\bar z_i}\partial_{\bar z_j}r(z_0)
\end{array}
\right]_{i,j=1,\dots,n}\;\;\;.
$$
Now we define the complex Hessian of $r$ as the block $(1,2)$ (or $(2,1)$, they are equal), i.e. the $n\times n$ matrix
$$
\Bbb CH[r]_{z_0}=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\partial_{z_i}\partial_{\bar z_j}r(z_0)
\end{array}
\right]_{i,j=1,\dots,n}\;\;\;.
$$

I have reason to believe the signature of $\Bbb CH[r]_{z_0}$ behaves in a strange way. Call it $(s^+,s^-,s^0)$; we know that $s^++s^-+s^0=n$. If $n\ge2$, I think the following conditions are true:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
s^+\ge1\\
s^++s^-\le n-1
\end{array}
\right.
\;\;.
$$

The reason I believe this is that these are necessary to make sum's index work in 1.6.6 of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215207/normal-coordinates-theorem-for-a-hypersurface.

Is this true? How can I prove it?

Comment: It is not true without further hypotheses.  For example, consider $r = -|z_1|^2 - \cdots - |z_n|^2$, which has $s^+=0$ and $s^-  = n$.

Comment: Hessian is not very meaningful unless you are at a critical point.

Comment: Ok thanks, you're right. But how can I explain the 1.6.6 of the link? The indexes are not correct: if I take $r$ as in the example we'd have (look at the two sums in 1.6.6) $s^++s^-+1=n+1$ and $s^++1=1$ which is meaningless. What's wrong with this?

Comment: @Joe:  You are reading too much into the notation in (1.6.6).  The author has been careless about choosing notation that includes the cases in which there are no negative signs and/or no positive signs.  Thus, you are literally right, but you should just keep in mind that the author should have mentioned that it is possible to have no negative and/or no positive terms in the Hermitian quadratic form.  That's all.

Comment: Many many thanks!! One last question: the two sums in (1.6.6) are over $n-1$ terms. So, the author doesn't take in account one eigenvalue. Which one is it? Can you help me please?